# Asp.Net CDN Minified JQuery Not Gzipped?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, google-cdn, microsoft-cdn

Does anyone know if there is a reason why the minified versions of the jQuery files on the Asp.Net content delivery network are not gzip compressed? The non-minified versions are properly compressed.

Examples:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js (GZipped)
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js (Not GZipped)

If I look at the Google CDN, the minified files are also gzipped. Unfortunately they are not offering jquery.unobtrusive-ajax, jquery.validate, or jquery.validate.unobtrusive.

[image: YSlow Output]

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public,max-age=31536000
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "075379efba5cb1:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 279431312700000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 2745
Age: 6009332
Date: Tue, 24 May 2011 18:13:59 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 27 Dec 2010 19:24:02 GMT
Expires: Thu, 15 Mar 2012 04:58:27 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Both gzipped when I check with fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was going on, but now the files are showing gzipped. As mentioned in one of my comments, it seemed to change when I went from one I.P. to the other.

Answer (score 3):

My FireBug sees them (both) gzipped:

[image]

Comment: I just checked in fiddler and it is compressed :) whew

Comment: added the output from yslow and the header contents from fiddler to my question.

Comment: @Sam, hmm, this is starting to be scary indeed. Could it be because you are hitting some different data center in which the web servers are not configured the same way as the one I am hitting? Could you post the IP addresses given by the following command on your machine: `nslookup ajax.aspnetcdn.com`?

Comment: 207.46.206.28 (same as given by ping), 207.46.206.127. Are you getting different IPs?

Comment: Don't know what changed, but I did another Ctrl+F5 and now the files are coming back gzipped through the Microsoft CDN.

Comment: I take it back. Now when I ping I am getting the 207.46.206.127 IP address. Perhaps it is only gzipped on one of the servers?

Comment: google PageSpeed Insights says they aren't compressed seems like a shame not not gzip and/or brotli them..

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy? At work our proxy rips out the compression on some files before it reaches each client

Comment: nope. and as you can see, it allows the has no problems with the google:)

Comment: You should meet our proxy - it's NOT consistent :)